# std::map::erase() - which overload is faster?

Tags: c++, dictionary

The map::erase() method has two overloads to remove a single item:

```
void erase ( iterator position );
size_type erase ( const key_type& x );
```

I need to check which version is likely to be faster - my guess would be the first, because the second probably has to call map::find() to look up the iterator?

Can anyone confirm?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an iterator to erase? If you have, use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one is amortized constant complexity, the second is logarithmic. It is unlikely that the constant term would be large enough to make the first version slower than the second, but I imagine they must be indistinguishable from each other for very small maps.

Comment: I'd go a little further: they're probably close to indistinguishable until/unless you're dealing with a really large map.

Comment: The second cannot be slower than the first (iterator based version). The logarithmic complexity of the value based erase comes from one find() (search the element) in the map and adds a constant factor for deleting it. So, whenever you have the iterator use it for earasing otherwise provide the value to erase().